# How to write a code to get data from one form to another form by using button?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have created a command button in the `CustGroup` form action pane.

I have added a new base enum edt field to both the `CustGroup` and `CustTable` tables and forms.

When you click on the button the data that was previously changed in the `CustGroup` table must be reflected in the cust table form.

I have written code in button on click event handler but it's not updating.

What to do, any suggestions?

Comment: add your code and any other helpful information

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to transfer a change of a new field in a customer group to all customers that share this customer group.

This kind of mass data update is usually not done by code in a form, because that code is executed on the client tier, which results in a bad performance. Instead, you should create a class that is set to execute on the server tier. If you create a `main` method for this class, you can easily create an action menu item for it, which let's you easily integrate the call to this class as a button in the `CustGroup` form.

In the `main` method you can access the `CustGroup` record for which the button was clicked via the `Args` object. This gives you the value of your new field that was changed. With this value, you can then use code similar to the following to update your customers:

```cs
public void updateCustomersWithNewCustGroupFieldValue(CustGroup _custGroup)
{
    CustTable custTable;

    ttsBegin;
    while select forUpdate custTable 
        where custTable.CustGroup == _custGroup.CustGroup
    {
        custTable.MyNewEnumField = _custGroup.MyNewEnumField;
        if (custTable.validateWrite())
        {
            custTable.update();
        }
        else
        {
            error('Please implement some error handling');
        }
    }
    ttsCommit;
}
```